# bash shell date parsing, start with specific date and loop through each day in month

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need to create a bash shell script starting with a day and then loop through each subsequent day formatting that output as %Y_%m_d

I figure I can submit a start day and then another param for the number of days.

My issue/question is how to set a DATE (that is not now) and then add a day.

so my input would be 2010_04_01 6

my output would be

```
2010_04_01
2010_04_02
2010_04_03
2010_04_04
2010_04_05
2010_04_06
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
[radical@home ~]$ cat a.sh 
#!/bin/bash

START=`echo $1 | tr -d _`;

for (( c=0; c<$2; c++ ))
do
    echo -n "`date --date="$START +$c day" +%Y_%m_%d` ";
done
```

Now if you call this script with your params it will return what you wanted:

```
[radical@home ~]$ ./a.sh 2010_04_01 6
2010_04_01 2010_04_02 2010_04_03 2010_04_04 2010_04_05 2010_04_06
```

Answer (score 12):

Very basic bash script should be able to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
start_date=20100501
num_days=5
for i in `seq 1 $num_days`
do 
    date=`date +%Y/%m/%d -d "${start_date}-${i} days"`
    echo $date # Use this however you want!
done
```

Output:    
2010/04/30 
2010/04/29 
2010/04/28 
2010/04/27 
2010/04/26

Comment: Awesome! Really clever solution

Comment: This would only work for 1..30. If you need to iterate for more than one month, than this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Note: NONE of the solutions here will work with OS X. You would need, for example, something like this:

date -v-1d +%Y%m%d

That would print out yesterday for you. Or with underscores of course:

date -v-1d +%Y_%m_%d

So taking that into account, you should be able to adjust some of the loops in these examples with this command instead. -v option will easily allow you to add or subtract days, minutes, seconds, years, months, etc. -v+24d would add 24 days. and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
inputdate="${1//_/-}"  # change underscores into dashes
for ((i=0; i<$2; i++))
do
    date -d "$inputdate + $i day" "+%Y_%m_%d"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Very basic bash script should be able to do this.

**Script:**  
#!/bin/bash        
start_date=20100501 
num_days=5 
for i in `seq 1 $num_days` 
do 
    date=`date +%Y/%m/%d -d "${start_date}-${i} days"` 
     echo $date # Use this however you want! 
done

**Output:** 
2010/04/30 
2010/04/29 
2010/04/28 
2010/04/27 
2010/04/26

Comment: In the above script, start the sequence from '0' in your case instead of '1'.

Comment: Also note that the tildes "`" went missing (from the shaded portions) due to the html formating.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *cal*, for example

```
YYYY=2014; MM=02; for d in $(cal $MM $YYYY | grep "^ *[0-9]"); do DD=$(printf "%02d" $d); echo $YYYY$MM$DD; done
```

(originally posted [here on my commandlinefu account](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/13134/loop-over-the-days-of-a-month-in-yyyymmdd-format))

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a date via command line option *-d* to GNU date handling multiple input formats:

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Date-input-formats

Pass starting date as command line argument or use current date:

```
underscore_date=${1:-$(date +%y_%m_%d)}
date=${underscore_date//_/-}

for days in $(seq 0 6);do 
    date -d "$date + $days days" +%Y_%m_%d;
done
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use gawk

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$1
num=$2
awk -vd="$DATE" -vn="$num" 'BEGIN{
   m=split(d,D,"_")
   t=mktime(D[1]" "D[2]" "D[3]" 00 00 00")
   print d
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      t+=86400
      print strftime("%Y_%m_%d",t)
   }
}'
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh 2010_04_01 6
2010_04_01
2010_04_02
2010_04_03
2010_04_04
2010_04_05
2010_04_06
2010_04_07
```